# Environment-specific appsettings not loading its data

Tags: .net-core

When I attempt to use custom appsettings.{environment}.json file, even though the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment var is correctly set to "Local" and the appsettings.Local.json file is referenced in the config sources, no data is read from it, only from appsettings.json

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {

            // Configure the app here.
            var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
            //var environmentName = 

            config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Showing values from appsettings.json
[image]

Showing config values from appsettings.Local.json (empty)

[image]

```
------ appsettings.json ----------------------
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AppSettings": {
    "MailServer": "mail.somewhare.com",
    "SupportContact": "somebody@somewhare.com",
    "EmailEnabled": true    
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}



------ appsettings.Local.json  ---------------
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Dbconn1": "string 1 here",
    "DbConn2": "string 1 here"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AppSettings": {
    "CustomerBoxRoot": "\\\\test1\\d$\\BoxFiles",
    "AnotherAppSetting": 20,
    "PurgeSwitch": -14
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is change it to `optional: false` and make sure it's finding the file. It shouldn't matter, but the source you're adding is actually `[5]` in the list you've shown.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  My build isnt generating it into the /bin folder